# Possible to show only errors in webpack?

Tags: webpack, command-line, config

When I have something changed in my files, webpack-watch shows a lot of text (3 times the image below). Which is driving me crazy, because I only want to see the file that has been changed, or the error(s) that might have occured. I overlook errors way to much because there is so much text.

Is it possible to only show errors, or only the real changed file? If so, how can I achieve this?

[image]

This is my config:

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: "./index.js",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    stats: { chunks: false } 
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname),
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [["@babel/env", { modules: false }], "@babel/react"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
       }
    ],
    noParse: [/aws-sdk/]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      "process.env.STATIC_PORT": JSON.stringify(process.env.STATIC_PORT),
      VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version)
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'bundle.css'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "./cb_icons", to: "cb_icons" }])
  ],
  node: { fs: "empty" },
  externals: [{ "./cptable": "var cptable" }, { "./jszip": "jszip" }],
  performance: { hints: false },
  watchOptions: {
   ignored: ['node_modules'],
   poll: 1000
 }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes can do it via `stats` option, according to the docs:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-stats-

If you want to log only error messages:

```
devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only'
  }
```

Also, take a look at this option:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-clientloglevel

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for you quick answer. I've added the stats: 'errors-only' . and also tried the clientloglevel:'errors'.

Both don't seem to work. I've saved the file and run the command docker-compose down and up, but webpack still shows like the image. If you have any experience with docker, do you know if should I rebuild my docker-container or something?

Comment: Docker can be a problem. Do you sure that there is an updated webpack config file in docker container?